# Illegal Argument Exception in JSF Page rendering with SelectManyCheckbox

Tags: jsf

I am getting the following exception when i try to render the multiple checkbox in JSF. Any Clues on this.

```
    root cause

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.initializeItems(SelectItemsIterator.java:212)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.hasNext(SelectItemsIterator.java:131)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer.java:129)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:878)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1620)
javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1613)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
```

Here is the code i am using this

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{eBean.oBean.selectedStdItems}" converter="javax.faces.Long">> 
    <f:selectItems value="{eBean.oBean.stdItems}" var="stdItems" itemLabel="#{stdItems.code}"  itemValue="#{stdItems.id}" />  
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Comment: Thanks guys looks like i was missing a "#" infront of one of the value elements. Why does JSF doesn't give me proper explaination.

Comment: mainly because the value "{eBean.oBean.stdItems}" is considered a valid value.  Most JSF tag attributes accept both literals and expressions as their values.  If you do not include the "#{}" delimiting characters, JSF will just assume you've provided a literal instead of an expression that needs to be evaluated.